# Position: fixed, relative, absolute

Tags: html, css

Есть div id="header"  у которого position: fixed
Есть еще один div class="content1" внутри которого div class="content" . У класса content1 position:relative. У класса content position: absolute. При прокручивании до блока с классом content1 все его элементы наводятся поверх шапки ("header"). Как сделать так чтобы header был поверх других элементов?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index

Answer (score 1):

У элементов, чье `position` = !static (absolute, fixed, relative) можно назначать `z-index`, то есть положение в по оси Z. По умолчанию все элементы имеют `z-index: 0;`. Поэтому если вы назначите:

```
#header {
    z-index: 1;
}
```

То все должно работать. Это надо делать в CSS.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Все никак не мог понять, зачем нужен z-index. Теперь понял)